# VBA: passing by value to a property call

Tags: ms-access, vba, pass-by-value, call-by-value

I have following code working.

```
Me.lbl1.Name
```

But I have a bunch of these labels, so how can I make the last line work?

```
Dim numberTry As Integer
numberTry = 1
Dim outputString As String
outputString = "lblCmd" & numberTry
Me.[outputString].Name
```

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to a control by name if you use parentheses () and drop the dot.

So:

```
outputString = "lblCmd" & numberTry
Me(outputString).Name
```